# Error in running exe file without Visual Studio: DLL not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, dll

I have a C# executable produced by Visual Studio 2010. I would like to run it on another machine without Visual Studio.

I've installed the Microsoft Visual 2010 C++ Redistributable Package x64. The problem is that it does not see a DLL library that I am using. I checked, and the dll is in the same folder of the executable.

I already solved this problem in the past but I forgot how and now I can not find the answer anymore.

How can I find out which DLL is still missing?

Comment: I disagree with the "too broad" close votes. IMHO there are not so many ways to debug issues like that.

Comment: I think it'll prompt you an exception when you're missing dlls.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug missing DLL issues like this:

1. Start [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)
2. Set a filter for your executable
3. Reproduce the issue (i.e. run your application)
4. Save the log in XML file format
5. Open the XML in [Process Monitor Log Analyzer](http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/procmonanalyzer/) (Disclaimer: I'm the author of that free tool)
6. Check from top down whether a DLL is missing

If you found out, which DLLs are needed, you should create a Setup which installs all the needed dependencies. I found the free [Innosetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) easy to understand.

Comment: @BrnLmx: if this solved your problem, you can check the green checkmark.

Comment: Hi Thomas,  thank you for the reply! My problem is that the DLL is a C-based DLL that I produced in a VS project.

The DLL is there, but it is not "seen" :-( ...

Comment: @BrnLmx: what do you get if you follow the steps in the answer?